# MDX Query using generate function and calculated members

Tags: sql, mdx, member, generate, mdx-query

I've been trying to solve this query for a while but I don't understand where I'm wrong.
The questions of the query is this one:

***Show the winners having a total winner rank points greater than the average winner
rank points in each continent by continent and year***

The query I have thought to solve this problem is the following:

```
with member media as sum(([Tournament].[Tourney Id].CURRENTMEMBER,
[Loser].[Player Id].allmembers),
[Measures].[Winner Rank Points])/ [Measures].[Conteggio di Match] member loserrank as 
([Tournament].[Tourney Id].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[Loser Rank Points]) member 
ratio as case when media = 0 then 0 else loserrank / media end select 
{media, loserrank, ratio} on columns,
GENERATE([Tournament].[Tourney Id].[Tourney Id].members, 
TOPCOUNT(([Tournament].[Tourney Id].CURRENTMEMBER,
nonempty(FILTER([Loser].[Player Id].[Player Id], [Measures].[Loser Rank Points] >0 
))), 1, ratio)) on rows 
from [DBXMLCD]
```

The result of this query is this:
[Query result]

[image: 1]

Media means that it is the average, the values of media and loserrank that come out to me are wrong because i ran a query in sql and the correct results obtained are different from these here and i think the problem is on the average calculation (media).

I hope you can give me a hand, thanks in advance, and for other doubts write me here and I will reply immediately.

Comment: you need to show all your table definitions, sample data